# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to run this code where data of a dictionary is saved in a separate csv file.
Here is the dict:

```
body = {
        'dont-ask-for-email': 0,
        'action': 'submit_user_review',
        'post_id': 76196,
        'email': email_random(),
        'subscribe': 1,
        'previous_hosting_id': prev_hosting_comp_random(),
        'fb_token': '',
        'title': review_title_random(),
        'summary': summary_random(),
        'score_pricing': star_random(),
        'score_userfriendly': star_random(),
        'score_support': star_random(),
        'score_features': star_random(),
        'hosting_type': hosting_type_random(),
        'author': name_random(),
        'social_link': '',
        'site': '',
        'screenshot[image][]': '',
        'screenshot[description][]': '',
        'user_data_process_agreement': 1,
        'user_email_popup': '',
        'subscribe_popup': 1,
        'email_asked': 1
}
```

Now this is the code to write in a CSV file and finally save it:

```
columns = []
rows = []
chunks = body.split('}')
for chunk in chunks:
    row = []
    if len(chunk)>1:
        entry = chunk.replace('{','').strip().split(',')
        for e in entry:
            item = e.strip().split(':')
            if len(item)==2:
                row.append(item[1])
                if chunks.index(chunk)==0:
                    columns.append(item[0])
        rows.append(row)
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = columns)
df.head()

df.to_csv ('r3edata.csv', index = False, header = True)
```

but this is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "codeOffshoreupdated.py", line 125, in <module>
    chunks = body.split('}')
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I know that dict has no attribute named split but how do I fix it?

Edit:
format of the CSV I want:

```
dont-ask-for-email, action, post_id, email, subscribe, previous_hosting_id, fb_token, title, summary, score_pricing, score_userfriendly, score_support, score_features, hosting_type,author, social_link, site, screenshot[image][],screenshot[description][],user_data_process_agreement,user_email_popup,subscribe_popup,email_asked
0,'submit_user_review',76196,email_random(),1,prev_hosting_comp_random(),,review_title_random(),summary_random(),star_random(),star_random(),star_random(),star_random(),hosting_type_random(),name_random(),,,,,1,,1,1
```

Note: all these functions mentioned are return values

Edit2:

I am picking emails from the email_random() function like this:

```
def email_random():
        with open('emaillist.txt') as emails:
                read_emails = csv.reader(emails, delimiter = '\n')
                return random.choice(list(read_emails))[0]
```

and the emaillist.txt is like this:

```
xyz@gmail.com
xya@gmail.com
xyb@gmail.com
xyc@gmail.com
xyd@gmail.com
```

other functions are also picking the data from the files like this too.

Comment: Body is a dictionary, "only" strings can be split. And dictionaries are it's own data type, so not sure why you imagine you can split it? :)

Comment: Is there any way to convert everything to string first then use Split?

Comment: @Sushanth yes, I am trying to save this json to csv using Pandas.

Comment: No idea with Pandas, but `json.dumps` is used for what you just asked.

Comment: @Torxed can you show me how?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the resulting CSV would look like?

Comment: @Hamatti I will update it in my question

Comment: @Hamatti Can you please check now?

Answer (score 2):

Since `body` is a dictionary, you don't have to a any manual parsing to get it into a CSV format.

If you want the function calls (like `email_random()`) to be written into the CSV as such, you need to wrap them into quotes (as I have done below). If you want them to resolve as function calls and write the results, you can keep them as they are.

```py
import csv


def email_random():
    return "john@example.com"


body = {
    'dont-ask-for-email': 0,
    'action': 'submit_user_review',
    'post_id': 76196,
    'email': email_random(),
    'subscribe': 1,
    'previous_hosting_id': "prev_hosting_comp_random()",
    'fb_token': '',
    'title': "review_title_random()",
    'summary': "summary_random()",
    'score_pricing': "star_random()",
    'score_userfriendly': "star_random()",
    'score_support': "star_random()",
    'score_features': "star_random()",
    'hosting_type': "hosting_type_random()",
    'author': "name_random()",
    'social_link': '',
    'site': '',
    'screenshot[image][]': '',
    'screenshot[description][]': '',
    'user_data_process_agreement': 1,
    'user_email_popup': '',
    'subscribe_popup': 1,
    'email_asked': 1
}

with open('example.csv', 'w') as fhandle:
    writer = csv.writer(fhandle)
    items = body.items()
    writer.writerow([key for key, value in items])
    writer.writerow([value for key, value in items])
```

What we do here is:

`with open('example.csv', 'w') as fhandle:`

this opens a new file (named `example.csv`) with writing permissions (`'w'`) and stores the reference into variable `fhandle`. If using `with` is not familiar to you, you can learn more about them from [this PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/).

`body.items()` will return an iterable of tuples (this is done to guarantee dictionary items are returned in the same order). The output of this will look like `[('dont-ask-for-email', 0), ('action', 'submit_user_review'), ...]`.

We can then write first all the keys using a list comprehension and to the next row, we write all the values.

This results in

```
dont-ask-for-email,action,post_id,email,subscribe,previous_hosting_id,fb_token,title,summary,score_pricing,score_userfriendly,score_support,score_features,hosting_type,author,social_link,site,screenshot[image][],screenshot[description][],user_data_process_agreement,user_email_popup,subscribe_popup,email_asked
0,submit_user_review,76196,john@example.com,1,prev_hosting_comp_random(),,review_title_random(),summary_random(),star_random(),star_random(),star_random(),star_random(),hosting_type_random(),name_random(),,,,,1,,1,1
```

Comment: Please check the edit 2 I made. It is picking emails from a separate file. I think they are strings so it should not have any problems. I will try your approach and update you

Comment: I get the same issue. Dict has no attribute items. Is it because I am using a different python version?

Comment: Okay it worked. thanks a ton. Your answer was explained in great details. It was helpfuil

Comment: I am running this code several times and I want to append all the data in a new line. How do I do that?

Comment: @bitch_ctrl It depends a lot on the structure of the rest of your script and how it's being run.

One way you could do is storing the headers (dict keys) in a list (to make sure they are always in the right order) and then on each run, checking if there already is some data on the CSV and if there is, only append a new row (with `open('example.csv', 'a'))`).

Comment: I made a file with the headings and then commented out the code where it copies the headings @Hamatti